# preg_match_all regex smilies

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've imported an old guestbook into drupal, but some smilies from old system will be deleted, so I need to delete it from my `content string`

smilies example: `:lol: :nice: ...`

as you can see all of them are inside `:` without spaces, this is my code but have some issues with spaces.

```
preg_match_all( '/\:(.*?)\:/', $string, $matches );
```

string example: `:p hello to everybody :lol:`

return `:p hello to everybody :`

So, I need to remove only the `:?:` 
Any ideas to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\:(\w+)\:/` or `/\:([^\s]+)\:/`

ps: not sure that you have to escape colons and you do not need parenthesis here, but it is up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

If the similes are all alphanumeric try this

```
'/\:[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}\:/'
```